# Artin's conjecture on primitive roots for perfect powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, primitive-roots

Let $a\neq -1,0,1$ be an integer. Write $a=(b^2c)^k$, where $b^2c$ is not a perfect power, and $c$ is squarefree. Artin's conjecture on primitive roots states that the asymptotic density of the set of prime numbers $p$ such that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ is
$$
\tag{$\star$}
A(a)=\begin{cases}
\left(\displaystyle\prod_{q|k,q\text{ prime}}\dfrac{q(q-2)}{q^2-q-1}\right)C,&c\not\equiv 1\pmod 4;\\
\left(\displaystyle\prod_{q|k,q\text{ prime}}\dfrac{q(q-2)}{q^2-q-1}\right)\left(1-\displaystyle\prod_{p|c,p\text{ prime}}\dfrac{-1}{p^2-p-1}\right)C,&c\equiv 1\pmod 4.
\end{cases}
$$
The formula is copied from [here](https://www.numericana.com/answer/constants.htm#artin).

Everything looks well, except that at certain inputs the formula can't work: Let $q\neq 2$ be a prime and $m$ be a positive odd integer. Write $qm=q^rm'$ with $m'$ not divisible by $q$, and $r\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then we have
$$
\tilde{q}^{qm}\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p\Leftrightarrow \tilde{q}^{m'}\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p,
$$
where
$$
\tilde{q}:=(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}q=\begin{cases}q,&q\equiv 1\pmod 4;\\ -q,&q\equiv 3\pmod 4.\end{cases}
$$
Here "$\Rightarrow$" is obvious; for "$\Leftarrow$", note that $\tilde{q}^{m'}\equiv 1\pmod 4$, so $\tilde{q}^{m'}$ being a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$ implies that $p\not\equiv 1\pmod q$, then
$$
\operatorname{ord}_{p}(\tilde{q}^{qm}) = \dfrac{\operatorname{ord}_{p}(\tilde{q}^{m'})}{\gcd(\operatorname{ord}_{p}(\tilde{q}^{m'}),q^r)} = \dfrac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1,q^r)} = p-1.
$$
(As concrete examples, we have
\begin{align*}
&q=3,m=1:-27=(-3)^3\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p\Leftrightarrow -3\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p;\\
&q=5,m=1:3125=5^5\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p\Leftrightarrow 5\text{ is a primitive root modulo }p.
\end{align*}
However, the formula ($\star$) gives
$$
\dfrac{A(\tilde{q}^{qm})}{A(\tilde{q}^{m'})} = \dfrac{q(q-2)}{q^2-q-1}\neq 1.
$$
So my question is: **Are numbers of the form
$$
((-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}q)^{qm},\quad q\neq 2\text{ prime},\quad m\text{ odd}
$$
the only inputs for which the formula ($\star$) is false?** (Assuming that Artin's conjecture is true, of course.) If not, could you please give a modified formula that would work for all $a$? Any hint/reference appreciated.